VSE: Set default import settings for Strips
When importing an image  to VSE, the Color Space is set to sRGB by default, I'm trying to get it to default to Display P3 instead.
Alternatively change Strip > Transform > Filter to Box by default instead of auto.
Reason being I work with images with transparency, and with the default settings, it creates this white line around my image whenever I scale or rotate it.
Changing these settings are the only way I've manage to remove the white lines, but it can be quite exhausting having to change this every time I import a new image or start a new file. If there is a setting I can change that will fix this and save as default start up, that will do as well!

